# How to remove line betwin images in flutter Row widget?

Tags: flutter

How to remove white line between images in flutter Row widget?
I need place four images on the screen, I colored images in red to see edges.

[image]

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/profile.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/services.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/content.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/menu.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Device iPhone 8 plus
ios 16
Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Does it happen if you replace image widget with Container or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give it a fixed width like wrapping it with `SizeBox()` like the following example

```
SizedBox(
  height: double.infinity,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  child: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.png'),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  color: Colors.red,
)
```

if you just wanna give a color to the background why you just make it like these

```
Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.red,
     ...)
```

or

```
Container(
   color: Colors.red
   ...
)
```

Comment: SizedBox helped, thank you! I used red color to be sure that line not belong to image